# Multinomial logit in R: mlogit versus nnet

Tags: r, non-linear-regression, stargazer, multinomial, mlogit

I want to run a multinomial logit in R and have used two libraries, [`nnet`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nnet/nnet.pdf) and [`mlogit`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/mlogit.pdf), which produce different results and report different types of statistics. My questions are:

1. What is the source of discrepency between the coefficients and standard errors reported by `nnet` and those reported by `mlogit`?
2. I would like to report my results to a `Latex` file using `stargazer`. When doing so, there is a problematic tradeoff:

   - If I use the results from `mlogit` then I get the statistics I wish, such as psuedo R squared, however, the output is in long format (see example below).
   - If I use the results from `nnet` then the format is as expected, but it reports statistics that I am not interested in such as AIC, but does not include, for example, psuedo R squared.

   I would like to have the statistics reported by `mlogit` in the formatting of `nnet` when I use `stargazer`.

Here is a reproducible example, with three choice alternatives:

```
library(mlogit)

df = data.frame(c(0,1,1,2,0,1,0), c(1,6,7,4,2,2,1), c(683,276,756,487,776,100,982))
colnames(df) <- c('y', 'col1', 'col2')
mydata = df

mldata <- mlogit.data(mydata, choice="y", shape="wide")
mlogit.model1 <- mlogit(y ~ 1| col1+col2, data=mldata)
```

The tex output when compiled is of what I refer to as "long format" which I deem undesired:

[image]

Now, using `nnet`:

```
library(nnet)
mlogit.model2 = multinom(y ~ 1 + col1+col2, data=mydata)
stargazer(mlogit.model2)
```

Gives the tex output:

[image]

which is of the "wide" format which I desire. Note the different coefficient and standard errors.

Comment: Did the answer help point you in the right direction? Traveling this weekend, though happy to help.

Comment: I am now looking into the answers, will keep you posted,  thank you kindly @Technophobe01

Answer (score 26):

To my knowledge, there are three  R packages that allow the estimation of the multinomial logistic regression model: `mlogit`, `nnet` and `globaltest` (from Bioconductor). I do not consider here the `mnlogit` package, a faster and more efficient implementation of `mlogit`.
All the above packages use different algorithms that, for small samples, give different results. These differencies vanishes for moderate sample sizes (try with `n <- 100`). 
Consider the following data generating process taken from the [James Keirstead's blog](http://www.jameskeirstead.ca/blog/how-to-multinomial-regression-models-in-r/):

```
n <- 40
set.seed(4321)
df1 <- data.frame(x1=runif(n,0,100), x2=runif(n,0,100))
df1 <- transform(df1, y=1+ifelse(100 - x1 - x2 + rnorm(n,sd=10) < 0, 0,
      ifelse(100 - 2*x2 + rnorm(n,sd=10) < 0, 1, 2)))
str(df1)
'data.frame':   40 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ x1: num  33.48 90.91 41.15 4.38 76.35 ...
 $ x2: num  68.6 42.6 49.9 36.1 49.6 ...
 $ y : num  1 1 3 3 1 1 1 1 3 3 ...
table(df1$y)
 1  2  3 
19  8 13
```

The model parameters estimated by the three packages are respectively:

```
library(mlogit)
df2 <- mlogit.data(df1, choice="y", shape="wide")
mlogit.mod <- mlogit(y ~ 1 | x1+x2, data=df2)
(mlogit.cf <- coef(mlogit.mod))

2:(intercept) 3:(intercept)          2:x1          3:x1          2:x2          3:x2 
   42.7874653    80.9453734    -0.5158189    -0.6412020    -0.3972774    -1.0666809 
#######
library(nnet)
nnet.mod <- multinom(y ~ x1 + x2, df1)
(nnet.cf <- coef(nnet.mod))

  (Intercept)         x1         x2
2    41.51697 -0.5005992 -0.3854199
3    77.57715 -0.6144179 -1.0213375
#######
library(globaltest)
glbtest.mod <- globaltest::mlogit(y ~ x1+x2, data=df1)
(cf <- glbtest.mod@coefficients)

                      1          2          3
(Intercept) -41.2442934  1.5431814 39.7011119
x1            0.3856738 -0.1301452 -0.2555285
x2            0.4879862  0.0907088 -0.5786950
```

The `mlogit` command of `globaltest` fits the model without using a reference outcome category, hence the usual parameters can be calculated as follows:

```
(glbtest.cf <- rbind(cf[,2]-cf[,1],cf[,3]-cf[,1]))
     (Intercept)         x1         x2
[1,]    42.78747 -0.5158190 -0.3972774
[2,]    80.94541 -0.6412023 -1.0666813
```

Concerning the estimation of the parameters in the three packages, the method used in `mlogit::mlogit` is explained in detail [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mlogit/vignettes/mlogit.pdf).
In `nnet::multinom` the model is a neural network with no hidden layers, no bias nodes and a softmax output layer; in our case there are 3 input units and 3 output units:

```
nnet:::summary.nnet(nnet.mod)
a 3-0-3 network with 12 weights
options were - skip-layer connections  softmax modelling 
 b->o1 i1->o1 i2->o1 i3->o1 
  0.00   0.00   0.00   0.00 
 b->o2 i1->o2 i2->o2 i3->o2 
  0.00  41.52  -0.50  -0.39 
 b->o3 i1->o3 i2->o3 i3->o3 
  0.00  77.58  -0.61  -1.02
```

Maximum conditional likelihood is the method used in `multinom` for model fitting.
The parameters of multinomial logit models are estimated in `globaltest::mlogit` using maximum likelihood and working with an equivalent log-linear model and the Poisson likelihood. The method is described [here](http://data.princeton.edu/wws509/notes/c6.pdf).

For models estimated by `multinom` the McFadden's pseudo R-squared can be easily calculated as follows:

```
nnet.mod.loglik <- nnet:::logLik.multinom(nnet.mod)
nnet.mod0 <- multinom(y ~ 1, df1)
nnet.mod0.loglik <- nnet:::logLik.multinom(nnet.mod0)
(nnet.mod.mfr2 <- as.numeric(1 - nnet.mod.loglik/nnet.mod0.loglik))
[1] 0.8483931
```

At this point, using `stargazer`, I generate a report for the model estimated by `mlogit::mlogit` which is as similar as possible to the report of `multinom`.
  The basic idea is to substitute  the estimated coefficients and probabilities in the object created by `multinom` with the corresponding estimates of `mlogit`.

```
# Substitution of coefficients
nnet.mod2 <- nnet.mod
cf <- matrix(nnet.mod2$wts, nrow=4)
cf[2:nrow(cf), 2:ncol(cf)] <- t(matrix(mlogit.cf,nrow=2))
# Substitution of probabilities
nnet.mod2$wts <- c(cf)
nnet.mod2$fitted.values <- mlogit.mod$probabilities
```

Here is the result:

```
library(stargazer)
stargazer(nnet.mod2, type="text")

==============================================
                      Dependent variable:     
                  ----------------------------
                        2              3      
                       (1)            (2)     
----------------------------------------------
x1                   -0.516**      -0.641**   
                     (0.212)        (0.305)   

x2                   -0.397**      -1.067**   
                     (0.176)        (0.519)   

Constant             42.787**      80.945**   
                     (18.282)      (38.161)   

----------------------------------------------
Akaike Inf. Crit.     24.623        24.623    
==============================================
Note:              *p<0.1; **p<0.05; ***p<0.01
```

Now I am working on the last issue: how to visualize loglik, pseudo R2 and other information in the above `stargazer` output.

Comment: Marco - Nice explanation and references - thanks for sharing. :-)

Answer (score 3):

If you are using stargazer you can use `omit` to remove unwanted rows or references. Here is a quick example, hopefully, it will point you int he right direction.

nb. My assumption is you are using Rstudio and rmarkdown with knitr.

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(mlogit)

df = data.frame(c(0,1,1,2,0,1,0), c(1,6,7,4,2,2,1), c(683,276,756,487,776,100,982))
colnames(df) <- c('y', 'col1', 'col2')
mydata = df

mldata <- mlogit.data(mydata, choice = "y", shape="wide")
mlogit.model1 <- mlogit(y ~ 1| col1+col2, data=mldata)
mlogit.col1 <- mlogit(y ~ 1 | col1, data = mldata)
mlogit.col2 <- mlogit(y ~ 1 | col2, data = mldata)

```

# MLOGIT

```{r echo = FALSE, message = TRUE, error = TRUE, warning = FALSE, results = 'asis'}
library(stargazer)
stargazer(mlogit.model1, type = "html")
stargazer(mlogit.col1, 
          mlogit.col2,
          type = "html",
          omit=c("1:col1","2:col1","1:col2","2:col2"))


```
````

### Result:

[image]

Note that the second image omits 1:col1, 2:col2, 1:col2 and 2:col2

[image]